# Using shared variable in Parallel For

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I am struggling in using Parallel.For in the below code instead of for loop.
Since the size of the CoefficientVector vector array is rather big, it makes sense to me only to reset the array elements value instead of creating it new for each iteration.

I try to replace the outer loop with Parallel For; and assuming each partition of the parallel for, ran by a separate thread, will have it's own copy of CoefficientVector class it therefore makes sense(?) to me to have one instance of the CoefficientVector object for each thread and reset the vector elements rather than recreating the array. I though find it hard to do this optimisation(?) on Parallel For. Could anyone help please.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        timer.Start(); 

        int numIterations = 20000;
        int numCalpoints = 5000;
        int vecSize = 10000;

        CalcPoint[] calcpoints = new CalcPoint[numCalpoints];

        CoefficientVector coeff = new CoefficientVector();
        coeff.vectors = new Vector[vecSize];

        //not sure how to correctly use Parallel.For here
        //Parallel.For(0, numCalpoints, =>){
        for (int i = 0; i < numCalpoints;i++)
        {
            CalcPoint cp = calcpoints[i];

            //coeff.vectors = new Vector[vecSize];
            coeff.ResetVectors();

            //doing some operation on the matrix n times
            for (int n = 0; n < numIterations; n++)
            {
                coeff.vectors[n].x += n;
                coeff.vectors[n].y += n;
                coeff.vectors[n].z += n;
            }

            cp.result = coeff.GetResults();
        }

        Console.Write(timer.Elapsed);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class CoefficientVector
{
    public Vector[] vectors;

    public void ResetVectors()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vectors.Length; i++)
        {
            vectors[i].x = vectors[i].y = vectors[i].z = 0;
        }
    }

    public double GetResults()
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vectors.Length; i++)
        {
            result += vectors[i].x * vectors[i].y * vectors[i].z;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

struct Vector
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;
}

struct CalcPoint
{
    public double result;
}
```

Comment: If you want to reset the vectors in you Vector array, why don't you use `Array.Clear(...)`? Array.Clear(...) sets each array element to its default value. This would work here, since structs are value types, and setting a Vector struct to its default value means setting each of its fields to its default value (which is zero for numerical types)...

Comment: Thanks @elgonzo. Perhaps I didn't explain it correctly. But each calc point needs to maintain it's own result. Using Parallel For and Array.Clear(...) will change the results of the other calc points. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. Just write your code using Parallel.Foreach. Do not worry yet about optimization. If you feel that your code is still too slow even with Parallel.Foreach, profile the code executed by Parallel.Foreach to see where further optimization efforts would pay off. (I assume the code you have given here is somewhat simplified, and the real matrix calculations are somewhat more complex)

Comment: @elgonzo. I liked your being cool on taking this optimisation anything serious :)

Comment: @elgonzo It is as you said. The calculation is actually ray tracing using matrix coefficient and time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parallel.For` method currently has 12 [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782869(v=vs.110).aspx). Besides the variations of `int`, `long`, `ParallelOptions` and `ParallelState` action arguments you can notice several having additional generic argument `TLocal` like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static ParallelLoopResult For<TLocal>(
    int fromInclusive,
    int toExclusive,
    Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<int, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally
)
```

> Executes a for loop with thread-local data in which iterations may run in parallel, and the state of the loop can be monitored and manipulated.

In other words, `TLocal` allows you to allocate, use and release some thread-local state, i.e. exactly what you need (`TLocal` will be your `CoefficientVector` instance per thread).

So you can remove the `coeff` local variable and use the aforementioned overload like this:

```
CalcPoint[] calcpoints = new CalcPoint[numCalpoints];

Parallel.For(0, numCalpoints,
    () => new CoefficientVector { vectors = new Vector[vecSize] }, // localInit
    (i, loopState, coeff) => // body
    {
        coeff.ResetVectors();

        //doing some operation on the matrix
        for (int n = 0; n < coeff.vectors.Length; n++)
        {
            coeff.vectors[n].x += n;
            coeff.vectors[n].y += n;
            coeff.vectors[n].z += n;
        }

        calcpoints[i].result = coeff.GetResults();

        return coeff; // required by the body Func signature
    },
    coeff => { } // required by the overload, do nothing in this case
);
```

Comment: That is Beautiful. Thanks.